change the default download location from c drive to R drive for all apps
We have implemented a new policy in the company to lock the C drive for all employees. We have created a new partition using a PowerShell script. However, the issue is that when the C drive is locked, employees won't be able to save files since all applications like email, Teams, Google Chrome, Firefox, and Microsoft Edge default to saving on the C drive. They also won't be able to use OneDrive. I need your assistance to solve this problem. Thank you.

You can't do that for all apps. Even when you moved the installation, download and other kinds of folders then many apps still require to read/write something on the C: drive. You can't have a read-only C drive. Anyway maybe this will be more suitable on serverfault

Btw, for what reason to lock C drive?

Since each application is different, each would need to have settings for storage, download and other locations changed. It seems you want users to operate in kiosk mode, q.v.

sorry, i mean restrict access to the C drive , not make it read only –=
